# jQuery height() failure in deeper div elements

Tags: jquery, html, height

So I'm creating this little website for a competition and I have the following problem. I have a javascript that is supossed to make the lenght of 3 side by side  elements equal.
But it doesn't seem to work (code below, below line). So I added another piece of code to the script to see, if anything was working (above line). This part worked perfectly. Code is below.

another piece of might be relevant information: the names of the classes in the second (failing) part of the code are generated by php-script.

Thanks a lot, you guys are lifesavers

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
     // this part of the code works
     var a=$("#homecontent").height();
     a = a*6;
     $("#homecontent").height(a);

//  ---------------------------------
     // this part of the code doesn't.
    var x=$("#pointer1").height();
    var y=$("#pointer2").height();  
    var z=$("#pointer3").height();
    if (x>=z && x>=y)
    {
      z=x;
    } 
    else if (y >= z && y >= x)
    {
      z=y;
    }
    $("#pointer1").height(x);
    $("#pointer2").height(x);   
    $("#pointer3").height(x);
});
```

EDIT: solution: I used classes instead of ID's in the original code so my script couldn't select my elements. When changed to ID's the following code worked

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
var x=$("#pointer1").height();
var y=$("#pointer2").height();  
var z=$("#pointer3").height();
var m = Math.max(x, y, z);
$("#pointer1, #pointer2, #pointer3").height(m);
});
```

Comment: ready handler doesn't wait for async content to be loaded, unlike window onload event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pop the link in I'll take a look but my hunch is that your elements when inspected don't have any height? Therefore you are just setting x, y and z as zero - leading to zero height elements. If you link me to the page I'll take a look. Try console.log(x); just after it is set.

Comment: http://sibstechnologies.com/index.html
I didn't show the php element, because it has other problems (but those I can fix myself as soon as I have physical access to my set-up

Comment: You have a javascript error on the page. Try instead of window.onload $(document).ready(function() { YOUR CODE }

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".pointer1").map(function ()
{
    return $(this).height();
}).get());

$(".pointer1").css("height", maxHeight);
```

Comment: Having just looked at your link, your markup only has three divs of *class*, not *ID*, `.pointer1`. There are no pointer2 or 3 elements. I've updated my answer to work with your markup.

Comment: hmm, I am using classes, so i changed that to ID's but it still fails sadly enough

Comment: That's because I updated my code example to use classes - did you change that too?